# my temperature is too high what can i do?

Tags: fermentation-temperature, temperature, temperature-control

i have just added all the ingredients for my first coopers lager beer kit. I am aware that my temperature is too high at 32degreesc and the kit says to be from 21-27. will this ruin it? i heard it was better to get the yeast in right away so i did that very quickly. (it does say on the kit that fermentation will still take place Can i put some ice cubes in to lower the temperature or is it bad to remove the lid? or maybe put it outside for a bit? thanks very much for any advice!

Answer (score 1):

If not ruin it, it will make fairly bad beer.  It is always better to wait til the wort reaches a good temp then to pitch the yeast at too high a temp.  You can put the fermenter into a bathtub or other container and add cold water and ice to the water.  Don't put ice directly into your wort.  Ice is not sanitary and you risk contaminating your beer by doing that.

Comment: thanks for the answer. it is now very slowly reducing down in temperature. the room that it is in is around 21 degrees.as its only been going an hour will it be salvageable?

Comment: Yeah, if it's only been an hour you should be OK.  If you could get it down another degree or so it would be perfect, but 21 is FAR better than 32!  Remember, fermentation creates it's own heat so the beer may very well be a few degrees warmer than ambient temp.  The first 48-72 hours are the most crucial for temperature.  after that, it doesn't matter as much it gets warm.  BTW, it's undoubtedly not a true lager.  If so, you'd have to ferment it at 12-13c and lager it at 2C after fermentation.